# Why is the prompt to allow the app to access Bluetooth not being shown after initializing CBCentralManager?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, delegates, core-bluetooth

I am attempting to use `CoreBluetooth` and have setup both `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` in my `info.plist`. On the tap of a button my `CBCentralManager` is initialized and the `centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)` delegate method is called.

However, I am not prompted to allow the app to access Bluetooth permissions. I do see the default prompt to turn on Bluetooth when Bluetooth is off, but no prompt to allow the app to use Bluetooth when Bluetooth is on. Instead, the delegate method is continually called.

From my understanding the prompt should show as soon as you initialize the CBCentralManager. Any ideas what could be going on here? I am using a phone with iOS 14 to test.

Comment: What state are you getting in the delegate method?  Have you previously allowed or denied access?  The user is only prompted once.  Usually deleting the app from the device and installing it again will reset the permissions request state

Comment: @Paulw11 I am getting unauthorized as the state. I have been deleting the app off my phone for each test that I do to reset the permissions request state.

Comment: Sometimes the permissions won't reset unless you reset the settings on your phone; If you look in settings for your app, what do you see for Bluetooth permissions?  Is the switch off?

Comment: @Paulw11 just checked and yes, the switch is off.

Comment: That means as far as iOS is concerned you have already been asked for permission and it is denied.  You need to turn it on manually at this point.  You can go to "Settings->General->Reset->Reset Location and Privacy" to force it to ask you again, but this will reset all of your privacy answers for all apps